# How to bookmark a radio station in iTunes?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, internet-radio

Currently, I need to remember all of my favorite radio stations. Plus, I always need to search those stations from a really big list iTunes provides. And, I get pissed when I need to switch station back-and-forth.

I want to bookmark those radio stations or create a direct link to them?
How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add radio stations to playlists in iTunes.

[image: iTunes screenshot]

It doesn't seem to always work, but I had best results when I first listened to a station and only then copied it to a playlist.

---

When you select *Advanced » Open Stream* and enter the stream URL directly, it's saved as a song in your music library. Just select it from there in the future (provided the stream URL doesn't change a lot).

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on the stream you want to bookmark, hold and drag it a little to the left until the sidebar appears, there you can drop it (either into a playlist or as a separate entry).